# Autocomplete removes focus on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, search

Currently when I type three letters into my searchbar the autocomplete will start to work and the keyboard starts to hide for mobile devices.

The code I use is

```
jQuery("input#search").focus();

jQuery("input#search").blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { jQuery("input#search").focus(); }, 0);
});
```

When I use this for android devices the autocomplete will remove the keyboard but bring it back right away but ios will start to just hide it again and again.

Is there another possibility to just say "Block everything that will remove the focus" or "When losing focus bringt it back right away"?

Comment: try `autocomplete="off"`  `autocorrect="off"` . `spellcheck="false" `  for the input element.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: make element **readonly** +  **disable** on `blur`  event  like.  `$("input#search").prop("readonly", true);  $('input#search').prop('disabled', true);
`   and after timeout remove again.

Comment: do you have the whole code for me .. I don't understand completly what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code snippet

```js
$("input#search").focus();

    $("input#search").blur(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $( this ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( this ).prop( "readonly", true );
        setTimeout(function() { $("input#search").focus(); }, 100);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search" />
```